# MooTools, MooDialog and confirmLinkClick

Tags: dialog, mootools

I'm having some problems using [MooDialog](https://github.com/arian/MooDialog/blob/master/README.md) using its `confirmLinkClick` option.

In the html section I have:

```
<a title="Delete Link" id="confirmLinkClick"
 href="admin_delete_link.php?links_id=<?php echo $row_view_links['links_id'];?>">
     <img src="../images/link_delete.png" alt="Delete Link" />
</a>
```

In my script section I have:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ 
    $('confirmLinkClick').confirmLinkClick(
                                  'Are you sure you wish to delete this link?'); 
});
```

Up top I have the CSS link to the MooDialog.css, links to mootools.js (latest), Overlay.js, Moodialog.js, and moodialog.confirm.js

I have basically copied the way the sample file that came with MooDialog shows how to call the confirm dialog (http://www.aryweb.nl/projects/MooDialog/), but I do not get anything coming up at all.

Testing the sample file, I get the confirm pop up. Using the above code (which is even using the same sample id setting), nothing, it completely ignores the javascript.

I've googled and stackoverflowed but can't seem to find any hints, and yes I'm new to this as well.
I'm sure it's probably something very simple that I'm overlooking, but I just can't seem to get it.

Comment: you must have a js exception or your confirmLinkClick does not exist at the time of the script block's execution - or you are rewriting it. events by id are not delegated so if the latter, it won't work.

Comment: Hmm I didn't get any notification of a response. Thanks for the response Dimitar. I've since switched to using the jquery dialog.